# Search icon on click popup search box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having troubles with icon and popup when icon is pressed. Here's part of the code:

```
<div class="searchlink" id="searchlink">
   <i class="fa fa-search fa-custom"></i>
   .... 
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var $searchlink = $('#searchlink');

    $searchlink.on('click', function(e) {
        var target = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
        if ($(target).attr('id') == 'searchlink') {
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('open');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Full code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as2joj4g/)

It is not showing when I press the icon, it shows if I press around icon. What should I change? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code has a couple of logic issues. Your primary issue is the use of `e.target` to get the element which raised the event. This is a problem as you have a lot of child elements within the event bound element. To solve it you can simply use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that raised the event.

Then you can remove the `if` statement checking the `id` of the element. This is redundant as the click event is bound to that `id`, so it will always be `true`.

Finally you can simplify the class checking logic by just using jQuery's `toggleClass()` method. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchlink').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/as2joj4g/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for explanations :-)

Comment: Would it be better to add `e.preventDefault();`?